# How to simulate command line argument in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, command, arguments, line

I want to test a shell script using `some-script.sh foo` on `ideone`.

In Python we might do something like `sys.argv.extend('foo')` to simulate command line argument.

How to simulate command line argument in bash?

Comment: use `$1,$2,...$n`

Comment: Or `$* ` or maybe `"$@"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To populate the variables `$1`, `$2` etc., you can use

```
set -- arg1 arg2
```